# Warning Test run will use DLL(s) built for framework .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0 and platform X86

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, resharper, dotcover

I want to run a test on Resharper DotCover but one my test project dosnet run resharper tests, but normal test explorer works fine.

> Warning Test run will use DLL(s) built for framework
>   .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0 and platform X86. Following DLL(s) do not
>   match framework/platform settings. HR.EmployeeContext.Domain.Test.dll
>   is built for Framework .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1 and Platform X86. Go
>   to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=236877&clcid=0x409 for more
>   details on managing these settings.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.13.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your test build CPU settings to any CPU and it should work like a charm.

[image: open to show detail]

Comment: same issue here... but the question is about .NETCoreApp Version 1.0 and 3.1 - seems the test runner is using 1.0 but the project is 3.1 - AnyCPU does not really change that